plotting 3-way interaction with ggeffects, theme changes not being applied to all facets
I'm using the plot and predict functions from ggeffects to plot a 3-way interaction. The plots are being generated, but when I try to apply theme changes they only get applied to the second facet, see below
library(ggeffects)
library(ggplot2)

dat_iris <- iris

dat_iris$Petal.Size <- ifelse(dat_iris$Petal.Length <= 3, "small", "big")

model_iris <- glm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width*Species + Petal.Width + Petal.Size, data = dat_iris)

gg_iris <- plot(ggpredict(model_iris, terms=c("Sepal.Width", "Species", "Petal.Width", "Petal.Size")),  colors = c("#190C3EFF", "#9C2964FF", "#F8870EFF"))

gg_iris

gg_iris +
  xlab("Sepal Width") +
  ylab("Sepal Length") +
  guides(color = guide_legend("Species"), fill = guide_legend("Species")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "#E5E5E5", linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 0.3),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
        plot.title = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9),
        legend.position = "right",
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size = 9),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "#F0F0F0", color = NA),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 4:8) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2:5)

The resulting image looks like this:

I have read the ggeffects documentation, which states that "Load library(ggplot2) and use theme_set(theme_ggeffects()) to set the ggeffects-theme as default plotting theme. You can then use further plot-modifiers, e.g. from sjPlot, like legend_style() or font_size() without losing the theme-modifications." However this is does not seem to work with normal ggplot2 theme adjustments. Even following the documentation here https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/ggeffects.html, theme changes only get applied to one facet
gg_iris + theme(legend.position = "bottom")


I also tried manually faceting like this plot(ggpredict(model_iris, terms=c("Sepal.Width", "Species", "Petal.Width")),  colors = c("#190C3EFF", "#9C2964FF", "#F8870EFF")) + facet_wrap(~"Petal.Size") but this resulted in super bizarre output.

Is there a way to get the theme changes applied to all facets?

ggeffects uses patchwork to arrange the plots (facets are used within each of the two main panels), so you can apply themes and scales in the way you would to a patchwork object.
That is, use & instead of + to apply themes and scales to all the plots in the arrangement, and plot_layout(guides="collect") to use the same legend for all plots.
So:
gg_iris +
  plot_layout(guides="collect") &
  xlab("Sepal Width") &
  ylab("Sepal Length") &
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 4:8) &
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2:5) & 
  guides(color = guide_legend("Species"), fill = guide_legend("Species")) &
  theme_minimal() &
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "#E5E5E5", linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 0.3),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
        plot.title = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size = 9),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "#F0F0F0", color = NA),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9))




Thanks so much! Is it possible to have the plots share the same x and y-axis labels?

Look at collecting axes in patchwork.  https://www.data-imaginist.com/posts/2024-01-05-patchwork-1-2-0/
